# Magento 1.9.0.1: I am getting this error when creating new store view. please help!

Tags: magento-1.9, php, sql

```
SQLenter code hereSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Trace:
#0 /public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /public_html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `core_st...', Array)
#4 /public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `core_st...', Array)
#5 /public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(756): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
#6 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(380): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchRow(Object(Varien_Db_Select))
#7 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Store.php(319): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->load(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Store), Array, 'code')
#8 /public_html/app/code/community/Ameex/Adminlog/Model/Observer.php(29): Mage_Core_Model_Store->load(Array)
#9 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338): Ameex_Adminlog_Model_Observer->getLog(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#10 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Ameex_Adminlog_Model_Observer), 'getLog', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#11 /public_html/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#12 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(527): Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#13 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php(160): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->preDispatch()
#14 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(407): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->preDispatch()
#15 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('save')
#16 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#17 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#18 /public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#19 /public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#20 {main}
```

NOTE: I **disabled** the **Ameex_Adminlog** module but the problem still exists.

Comment: Remove cache and session folder if not work then Place getlog method of observer class

Comment: How did you disable Ameex Adminlog module? I think you have disabled module output from admin panel, while module should have been disabled from app/etc/modules/Ameex_Adminlog.xml file.

Comment: @MohitKumarArora and Same the combination of your suggestions solved the problem. can't thank you enough.